# Optaplanner change and reload drl

Tags: optaplanner

Is it possible, while solving a problem, to change something in the drl file and reload it in the solution without stoping the solver ?
Like we do with a problem fact.

If not, how can I proceed without loosing all the solution calculated previously.

Best regards.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Only during a `ProblemFactChange` that would be legal (that's a safe point), but currently it's not supported out-of-the-box. Internally, it would require either replacing the `ScoreDirectoryFactory` - or better yet, use drools's KieScanner functionality to simply upgrade the existing KieContainer.

Please create a jira ticket for this in our issue tracker and explain the use case a bit better.

You can always run a solver that starts from the solution calculated by another solver: the Construction Heuristics won't do anything if all vars an initialized.

Comment: Actually there is two use case.
First to edit value like threshold written in the drl rules.
Second to add/modify/remove rules.

Comment: For first, see the Parametrization pattern in the examples. Can be changed by problem fact change events.